# Action Mapping in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, migration, struts-1, action-mapping

Currently migrating an app from Struts1 to Struts2.
When I click my "submit" button, it gives me an error saying "There is no Action mapped for action name requestInput". What is wrong with my code that is the cause of this error?

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>My Project</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- The Usual Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <include file="struts-default.xml" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="uploadFile">
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
                <interceptor-ref name="uploadForm" />
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
                <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        

        <action name="requestInput" class="com.class.action.FileAddAction" method="execute">
            <result>/result.jsp</result>
        </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```

FileAdd.jsp

```
<s:form method="POST" action="requestInput" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<s:submit property="submit" style="background:#dccaa0" value="Submit" theme="simple"/>
...
</s:form>
```

FileAddAction.jsp

```
public final class FileAddAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware {
...
public String execute() throws Exception{
...
}
}
```

And, my struts.xml is in the Java src folder and in the WEB-INF folder.
What else can I do to fix this? Thanks..

Comment: What version of S2? The `ng` package isn't called that anymore. You don't need to manually include the `struts-default` config; your package already extends `struts-default`. You don't need to specify the default `method` on actions. I'd first check your startup logs to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I'm using the ```struts2-core-2.3.37.jar``` file, so version 2.3.37. What is the ```ng``` package called with this version?

Comment: Probably that; I don't remember--version 2.3 is pretty old at this point, multiple years. 2.5.x is the current version.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with struts, what kind of effort would it be to migrate an app using struts1 to struts version 2.5.x? Aside from the tags, is the Action functionality pretty similar?

Comment: Not even remotely. If your S1 app separated concerns appropriately it'll be much easier, but you're still looking at a front-end rewrite (some of which can be partially automated) and web-to-business layer rewrite. You can do this piece-by-piece, but it's still (roughly) a re-write.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Any advice on what else to double-check for why the Action isn't working for version 2.3? Does location of struts.xml matter, etc? I'm truly at a loss.

Comment: Yes, check your startup logs for errors. It belongs on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, otherwise looks good.

**First issue:**

> action name="requestInput" class="com.class.action.FileAddAction"
> method="execute"

You can't name your package with the identifier `class`, it is not a valid Java identifier

**Second issue:**

> interceptor-ref name="uploadForm"

What is "uploadForm"? It's definitely not provided by Struts 2, see the [list](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors.html#framework-interceptors).

By naming the package differently, and removing `interceptor-ref uploadForm`, i am able to click the `FileAdd.jsp Submit` button without any issue and it is redirecting me successfully to `result.jsp`. I used v2.3.37.

**Note:**

- `struts.xml` should be in the `src/main/resources` folder (struts.xml must be on the web application’s root class path). Check [this](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#step-6---create-strutsxml) out.
- `web.xml` is to be under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder. Check [this](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html#step-5---add-struts-2-servlet-filter) out.

Comment: I followed your advice but I'm still getting the same issue when I click the submit button: "There is no Action mapped for action name requestInput". Did you add the struts.xml or something else specifically onto the classpath? Or possibly in some other part of my code..?